# Java GridBagConstraints gridx and gridy not working?

Tags: java, swing, awt, jframe, jpanel

I am trying to use the `gridx` and `gridy` constraints to position my button. But they do not work! If I change the `gridx` and `gridy` variables, nothing happens. If I change the fill to `GridBagConstraints` to `NONE`, it still does not work.

Am I missing something here?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Window extends JFrame{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI");
    JTextField username = new JTextField(20);

    public void CreateWindow(){
        JPanel pane = new JPanel();
        pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;

        JButton button = new JButton("Button 1");
        c.weightx = 1.0;
        c.weighty = 1.0;
        c.gridx = 3;   //Has no effect
        c.gridy = 5;   //Has no effect
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;//If I remove this, it still does not work.
        pane.add(button, c);                    
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 600);
        frame.setResizable(true);           
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);          
        frame.add(pane);
        frame.setVisible(true);    
    }
}
```

If that is hard to read, here is where the problem lies:

```
JPanel pane = new JPanel();
            pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;

            JButton button = new JButton("Button 1");
            c.weightx = 1.0;
            c.weighty = 1.0;
            c.gridx = 3;   //Has no effect
            c.gridy = 5;   //Has no effect
            c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;    //If I remove this, it still does not work.
            pane.add(button, c);
```

Comment: ._. gridx and gridy dont affect the button. did you even read the question?

Comment: @Ken, Could you give us a visual representation of the desired layout? Perhaps then we could suggest different (and more appropriate) layout managers...

Comment: The button position is not changed by gridx and gridy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been a while since I've done swing layouts, but don't gridX and gridY only have effects if you have more than one JComponent in your JPanel? It seems you only have a JButton, so the GridBagLayout doesn't have any layout to do.

Comment: I believe Kane is correct.  Try adding some empty JLabels in the other positions and see if you get better results.  Also read up on the weightx and weighty settings. Without those, your components will group together in the center of the frame.

Comment: Im not too sure. So you're saying that I have to add another JComponent? I'm following a tutorial, and it works in there.

Comment: Could you post the tutorial you're using?

Comment: huzzah! Glad we could help. You should accept the answer to other people that read it will know the solution.

Comment: Kane, I am encountering same issue, but this time there are more than one Jcomponents in my panel and grid x and grid y are not working properly neither reflecting to any change. One more point, I am using swixml while rendering this UI.