# Why is the gridbagconstraint not working

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, gridbaglayout

I have used a grid bag constraint, when I use the insets to add the spacing that works fine however when I use the gridx and gridy to set the position nothing happens. I just posted the entire code below, I don't know if  this would help, thanks

```
import javax.swing.*;import java.awt.BorderLayout;import java.awt.CardLayout;importjava.awt.Color;import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;import java.awt.GridBagLayout;import java.awt.Insets;import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;importjava.awt.event.ActionListener;importjavax.swing.ImageIcon import javax.swing.JFrame;import javax.swing.JLabel;import javax.swing.JScrollPane;importjavax.swing.JTree;import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;public class MyWizard {
private JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Wizard");
private JPanel panelContainer = new JPanel();
private JPanel panelFirst = new JPanel();
private JPanel panelSecond = new JPanel();
private JPanel panelThird = new JPanel();

private JPanel panelButton = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

private JButton btNext = new JButton ("Next");
private JButton btNextTwo = new JButton ("Next");
private JButton btNextThree = new JButton("Next");
private JRadioButton btLdap, btKerbegos, btSpnego, btSaml2;
private JCheckBox btSan, btNFS, btYUMserver;
private CardLayout c1 = new CardLayout();
private JScrollPane scrollPane;
private JLabel lblPicture, lblPictureTwo;
DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("FMW Components");


public MyWizard() {
    //tree code
    final DefaultMutableTreeNode accessibility =
            add(root, "DB Tier", true);
    add(accessibility, "RAC", false);
    add(accessibility, "Gateways", false);
    add(accessibility, "Datavault", false);
    add(accessibility, "Agent", false);
    add(accessibility, "Custom Databases", false);
    root.add(accessibility);

    final DefaultMutableTreeNode browsing =
            new DefaultMutableTreeNode("APP Tier");
    add(browsing, "IDM (OID, OVD)", false);
    add(browsing, "IAM (Access Manager)", false);
    add(browsing, "BIEE", false);
    add(browsing, "Forms and Reports", false);
    add(browsing, "Discoverer", false);
    add(browsing, "Apps", false);
    add(browsing, "Apex(4.2.1)", false);
    root.add(browsing);

    final DefaultTreeModel treeModel = new DefaultTreeModel(root);
    final JTree tree = new JTree(treeModel);

    final CheckBoxNodeRenderer renderer = new CheckBoxNodeRenderer();
    tree.setCellRenderer(renderer);

    final CheckBoxNodeEditor editor = new CheckBoxNodeEditor(tree);
    tree.setCellEditor(editor);
    tree.setEditable(true);
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tree);
    //tree code ends

    panelFirst.setLayout(null); 
    panelSecond.setLayout(null); 
    panelThird.setLayout(new BorderLayout());


    panelContainer.setLayout(c1);
    panelFirst.add(btNext);
    panelSecond.add(btNextTwo);


    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);

    //this is not working
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 0;

    panelButton.add(btNextThree, gbc);
    panelThird.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panelThird.add(panelButton,  BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    panelFirst.setBackground(Color.white);
    panelSecond.setBackground(Color.white);

    panelContainer.add(panelFirst, "1");
    panelContainer.add(panelSecond,"2");
    panelContainer.add(panelThird,"3");
    c1.show(panelContainer, "1");


    btNext.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            c1.show(panelContainer,"2");

        }

    });

    btNextTwo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            c1.show(panelContainer,"3");

        }

    });
    RadioButtons();
    Button();
    Buttons();
    CheckList();
    groupButton();
    Image();
    frame.add(panelContainer);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setSize(400,310);
    frame.setVisible(true); 
}


public void RadioButtons() {
    btLdap = new JRadioButton ("Ldap");
    btLdap.setBounds(60,85,100,20);
    btLdap.setBackground(Color.white);
    panelFirst.add(btLdap);

    btKerbegos = new JRadioButton ("Kerbegos");
    btKerbegos.setBounds(60,115,100,20);
    btKerbegos.setBackground(Color.white);
    panelFirst.add(btKerbegos);

    btSpnego =new JRadioButton("Spnego");
    btSpnego.setBounds(60,145,100,20);
    btSpnego.setBackground(Color.white);
    panelFirst.add(btSpnego);

    btSaml2 = new JRadioButton("Saml2");
    btSaml2.setBounds(60,175,100,20);
    btSaml2.setBackground(Color.white);
    panelFirst.add(btSaml2);
}

public void Button() {
    btNext.setBounds(250,240,100,20);
}

public void CheckList () {
    btSan = new JCheckBox ("San");
    btSan.setBounds(60,85,100,20);
    btSan.setBackground(Color.white);
    panelSecond.add(btSan);

    btNFS = new JCheckBox ("NFS");
    btNFS.setBounds(60,115,100,20);
    btNFS.setBackground(Color.white);
    panelSecond.add(btNFS);

    btYUMserver =new JCheckBox("Spnego");
    btYUMserver.setBounds(60,145,100,20);
    btYUMserver.setBackground(Color.white);
    panelSecond.add(btYUMserver);
}

public void Buttons() {
    btNextTwo.setBounds(250,240,100,20);
}



public void Image() {
    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("iconpic.png");
    lblPicture = new JLabel(image);
    lblPicture.setBounds(140,5, 330, 270);
    panelFirst.add(lblPicture);

    ImageIcon imageTwo = new ImageIcon("iconpic.png");
    lblPictureTwo = new JLabel(imageTwo);
    lblPictureTwo.setBounds(140,5, 330, 270);
    panelSecond.add(lblPictureTwo);
}

private void groupButton() {

    ButtonGroup bg1 = new ButtonGroup( );

    bg1.add(btLdap);
    bg1.add(btKerbegos);
    bg1.add(btSpnego);
    bg1.add(btSaml2);

}

private static DefaultMutableTreeNode add(
        final DefaultMutableTreeNode parent, final String text,
        final boolean checked)
{
    final CheckBoxNode data = new CheckBoxNode (text, checked);
    final DefaultMutableTreeNode node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(data);
    parent.add(node);
    return node;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new MyWizard();
        }
    });

}}
```

Comment: there needs to be some more code - where do you set the LayoutManager for panelButton? Which other components are layouted in the component panelButton? (what is panelButton by the way?)

Comment: Have you set the layoutmanager for the `panelButton` using `panelButton.setLayout(new GridBagLayout())` or some other way?

Comment: panelButton is a JPanel, this panel is inside another panel and is set to BorderLayout south, panelButton itself has no Layout Manager it only has a JButton

Comment: I have this  private JPanel panelButton = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

Comment: I just did what you said with pabelButton.setLayout(new GridBagLayout()); it made no difference

Comment: well the gbc applies to the btNextThree-component you put inside the panelButton - not to the JPanel panelButton itself. Changes in gridx/gridy can only be seen, if there are any more components in panelButton which go in different cells of the layout.

Comment: Don't post the code here in the comments, post it in the question above  and post a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401367/java-gridbagconstraints-gridx-and-gridy-not-working

Comment: I'll post the entire code

Comment: The button is the only component inside `panelButton`. Therefore changing its position in the grid has no effect. (It's difficult to tell what constraints exactly you should be using, as I don't know what you want the layout to look like; Also, `GridBagLayout` is likely overkill if the intent is to just position one component).

Comment: You have added only one object to `panelButton` so you may not see any difference.

Comment: At the moment the button in panelButton is in the center but I just want to move it to the far right, what is the best way to do that?

Comment: I'd probably use a vertical BoxLayout + right alignment. With `GridBagLayout` you can use `gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I move the image in GUI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18233214/how-can-i-move-the-image-in-gui)

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you have some serious misunderstandings of the workings of `GridBagLayout`. In your current code, there is only one `JComponent` inside your `GridBagLayout`... and that is `btNextThree`.

Here is where you added it into the Grid.

`panelButton.add(btNextThree, gbc);`

> "At the moment the button in panelButton is in the center but I just
>   want to move it to the far right, what is the best way to do that?".

You can't do that with GridBagLayout... at least not the way you think. The cells in the Grid of GridBagLayout don't have a size until they have a component added to them, so where you have added `btNextThree` to;

```
gbc.gridx = 1;
gbc.gridy = 0;
```

It is now in the right-most cell in a grid of two columns and one row. However, the left-most column has no size, as it only has potential space inside it. Therefore, your right column with `btNextThree` inside takes up all available space.

So after all my babbling the short answer is that you should probably use another `LayoutManager`. But if you want a quick dirty fix you could create a second invisible component of roughly the same size as `btNextThree` and add it to the left most column, which would space them out evenly into two even columns. The below code should do that.

```
GridBagConstraints gbc2 = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc2.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);
gbc2.gridx = 0;
gbc2.gridy = 0;

panelButton.add(jButtonThatsSetToInvisible, gbc2);
```

If you later want them to stay correctly aligned within their container when resizing you may have to play with the `GridBagConstraints` weight attributes, but that is for another post I think.